# Angular 2 webpack api proxy

Tags: angular, http, angular2-services, webpack-dev-server

I am using Angular 2 + Webpack. I am serving my application with localhost:8000/app. I want to settup a proxy for my api so that they are not served from localhost otherwise from a web address. By referring to the solution on https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html, it does not do anything. My webpack configuration for proxy is:

```
        devServer: {
        port: 8000,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/app'
        },
        quiet: false,
        stats: { colors: true },
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        setup: function(app) {
            app.use('/app/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
        },

    proxy: {
            "/appApi": {
            "target": {
                "host": "somewebsite.com",
                "protocol": 'http:',
                "port": 80
            },
            ignorePath: true,
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure: false
            }
        }

    }
```

My angular request is:

```
this.http.get('appApi/getData', 
              headers
              ).subscribe(res => {console.log(res)});
```

When looking at the request, appApi/getData still served from:

localhost:8000/app/appApi/getData

I am expecting the proxy to work and the end point be:

http://somewebsite.com/appApi/getData

Comment: Are you using webpack 1 or webpack 2?

Comment: i am using 2.1.0-beta